# Как сверстать блок c такими рамками?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image]

Есть идеи как сверстать фиксированный блок с такими рамками? Картинка сплошная, сделана бекграундом. Пробовал таким образом, но при добавлении текста все ломается.

```css
.block {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 318px;
}

.block-1 {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 739px;
 padding: 35px;
 padding-right: 0;
 border: 3px solid #fff;
 border-right: none;
}

.block-2 {
 width: 198px;
 margin-left: -4px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

.block-3 {
 width: 198px;
 margin-left: -3px;
 border: 3px solid #fff;
 border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block-1 block"></div>
  <div class="block-2 block"></div>
  <div class="block-3 block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если заведомо известно, что человек будет "под рамкой" **только** снизу или сверху, то сымитировать нижнюю или верхнюю рамку можно псевдоэлементами `:before` или `:after` соответственно:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: lightblue;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 580px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: #fff solid 2px;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 40px 270px 40px 20px;
}

.block:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.block-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.block-img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 10px;
  top: -40px;
  width: 250px;
}

.block-img img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div class="block-img">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/piEec.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```